# Why do I have warning "C4199 two-phase name lookup is not supported for C++/CLI, C++/CX, or openmp"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-warnings

I have many templates in my project. Everything is running fine but I've been getting this warning many times for a long time now. Should I keep ignoring it or should I use `#pragma warning(disable : 4199)`?

Comment: What happens, if you use the switch `/Zc:twoPhase-` like the warning suggests?

Comment: Find more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-en/cpp/build/reference/zc-twophase?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Simon [Fixed link](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/reference/zc-twophase?view=vs-2019). Basically, the C++/CLI, C++/CX and openmp variants of the compiler do not support two-phase name lookup. Sorry.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ok Thanks to Simon and Raymond's article I was able to solve it. I no more have that warning anywhere in my code. Just added the command as the article describes at it's very bottom.

Here's an image of where exactly I added the command for those like me that might have trouble finding it.

[image: MSVC twoPhase option]

Comment: I ran into this because my CLR project had [`/permissive-`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=vs-2019) set under All Options > Additional Options. Nowadays, when you create a C++ project through Visual Studio, it will automatically set `/permissive-`, _unless_ it's a CLR project.

Comment: I found this option under "C/C++"/Language as the option "Conformance mode", with the values Default, Yes (/permissive-) and No (/permissive). Selecting Default solved the problem for me.