# Error when installing package "Newtonsoft.Json"

Tags: json.net, nuget, visual-studio-2019

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.2'. You are trying to install this 
package into a project that targets 'native,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any 
assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, 
contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets. 
   Instal
```

Comment: make sure the console window is pointing to correct solution.

Comment: Hi, what's your project type? C++/CLI project?

Comment: See [Github/nuget/#8195](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8195#issue-452574911)... This is expected behavior if you're trying to install one nuget package into CLL/ClI project since this scenario is not supported now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cause of the error:

This error always occurs when you try to install one nuget package into `C++/CLI` project. Though `C++/CLI` project is managed code, for now `Nuget` doesn't support this scenario.

There's one open issue in Github/Nuget, see [#8195](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8195), you can track this issue to get notifications if there's any update.

> Workarounds:

1. You can try [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33505176/10910450), it helps many members with similar issue.
2. For me, since a nuget package is actually a `xx.zip` file which contains assemblies and some files. We can download the `xx.nupkg`(nuget package) file [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

[image]

Then you'll get one `xx.nupkg` file, rename it to `xx.zip` and extract it. You can now see a `lib` folder which includes assemblies for different target framework. If your C++/CLI project targets .net framework 4.5 and above, choose the `net45` folder. If your project targets .net framework 4.0, choose the `net40` folder...

We can copy the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` and `Newtonsoft.Json.xml` to project directory or any local folder. Then right-click project=>Add reference=>browse=> to add that reference manually. After that, type `using namespace Newtonsoft` to check if Intellisense can recognize this reference well.

[image]

If you meet error C4199 when compiling and building this project like me, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56785778/10910450).

Hope all above helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the error using Daniel's answer. But I got another error as state here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595826/erroring-about-using-push-back-function-in-visual-studio-2019-for-azure-kinect). Could you see whether you could help me with that